# Scattering theory of Dirac equation in curved space-time in presence of a strong magnetic field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, curvature, s-matrix-theory

What is the exact solution of the Dirac equation in curved space-time in the presence of a strong magnetic field? The solution should be in momentum space for simplicity to calculate scattering cross sections.

Comment: Dirac equation describes a free fermion, so I'm not sure what you mean by a Dirac equation in a strong magnetic field? For that you would need QED and not simply Dirac. Perhaps I misunderstood the question?